# Exponential disk usage in Ontotext GraphDB Platform

Tags: rdf, diskspace, graphdb, triplestore

We are facing some issues using graphdb 9.1 free edition: our disk usage its increasing in an exponential way.
I used the https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/requirements.html#hardware-sizing reference along with the following query to count triples:

`SELECT (COUNT(?s) AS ?triples) WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }`

Below, you can see the size of each folder of the graphdb installation we have:

**March 7**

83G     ./data

4.9G    ./logs

30M     ./work

4.0K    ./conf

88G     .

Triples count 192.567.172

**March 14**

109G    ./data

5.0G    ./logs

30M     ./work

4.0K    ./conf

114G    .

Triples count 199.287.593

In 7 days, we incresed the number of triples by 3% and the disk usage by almost 30%.
Could anyone give us any help to understand this behavior?

We double checked that we are not ingesting extra triples in our applications and everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 2):

It may be caused by the rule set and related settings on your repository that can cause additional triples to be inserted.

By default if you go to your repo in the workbench you would see
[image: Ruleset]

RDFS-Plus is the default setting on a repo. This will cause inferences to add triples to your repo when triples are inserted. The triples that are added by the ruleset, can cause further triples to be added. This happens at insert and is actually added to the triple store, not at query time.

If you want no inferences you should have "no inference" selected:

[image: No inference]

It will be difficult to find triples that have been added by the ruleset. You can find the rules in configs/rules/builtin_RdfsRules-optimized.pie.

Comment: We are using RDFS-Plus opt rule set and SHACL validation is disabled. Is assumed that the Ruleset was applied at the "query" time and only if you activate reasoning. Are you confirming that every single time I add some set of triples GraphDb is creating every single RDFS inference and storing that in the storage folder?
If that is right, is there a way to query the number of triples/statements including the rdfs ones?
I used that query (SELECT (COUNT(?s) AS ?triples) WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }) with reasoning enabled and the output is the one present in my question. Then the concern is the same.

Comment: Updated answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks Henriette. But the count of triples is taking into consideration the infered ones. So I still don't understand why if my number of triples grew by 3% the disk space usage had increased by almost 30%. I am wondering if it is something related to cache, indexed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using inference, GraphDB utilizes forward changing reasoning, meaning all statements are materialized on load.

You could read more about this using following link:
https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.2/architecture-components.html?highlight=forward%20chaining#reasoner-trree-engine

Obviously this is a corner case of an untypically long chain of entities related via transitive property. Still, it gives you an idea of what schema change can result in big inference. Another example would be defining two properties as inverse to one another or adding a new super class, which ends up having plenty of instances after inference.

Did you had changes like that? Or did you loaded a new version of a 3rd party dataset, which can contain such change?